# Bitrix Значения свойств в отдельной таблице инфоблока

Tags: php, битрикс, cms

Всем привет, имеется bitrix, значения свойств инфоблока хранятся в отдельной таблице.
А как посмотреть где эта отдельная таблица ???
Пару часов пытаюсь решить проблему, 
Искал в гугле так и не наткнулся, помогите добрые люди.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4):

b_iblock_element_prop_m<_ID_Инфоблока_> и b_iblock_element_prop_s<_ID_Инфоблока_> вроде. Только зачем вам это? Скорее всего вы задумали что-то не правильное ;)

Comment: дело в том что, при смене значения свойств из админ панели, само значение не меняется
очень странно, id инфоблока верный id свойства тоже верный.

Comment: Может быть у вас реализованы обработчики событий сохранения элементов, где блокируются изменения этих свойств. Может тип этих свойств пользовательский и имеет свою логику.